# ActiveResource error response header doesn't return body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I asked something similar to this before and never got an answer, here's a shortened version

I have a User activeresource model.  I make a simple call on my client to the service

```
response = User.find(id).put(:activate, :activation_code => activation_code)
```

If there were errors on the service (ie. activation_code didn't match) I return

```
render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
```

So apparently any error response with activeresource must be handled by a resue

```
rescue ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid
```

That's all fine and dandy, except that the response in the initial call does not get set.  I have no body from that response at all, so @user.errors is never returned.  What do I need to get the proper object back?  besides returning 200.  Any 'success' response code populates the response variable fine.  But always returning 200 seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was a bit mistaken there, in the rescue block

```
rescue ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid => e
```

e gets populated.  The service returns

```
render :xml => @user.errors, :unprocessable_entity
```

So e.response.body contains the errors xml.  I then on my client side just say

```
user.errors.from_xml(e.response.body)
```

and the user is now populated with the proper errors.